# Using jquery dialog for editing table

Tags: jquery, dialog, edit

need help.. this is my situation, i want to make an edit form via jquery dialog, to edit a table that populate its contents from mysql query, i have created this form and did show the modal dialog to edit but here are the problem comes when  click save or close button it close the dialog, but not only one dialog that show it'show dialog as many as record that i have from my query, and i have to click button again, thank's for help..

```
<table id='asset'>
    <tr><td>
        <a href='#'  class='edithistory' >edit</a>
        <form class ='formedithistory'>             
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Serial Number</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='serial_number_edit' id='serial_number_edit' value='$serial_number_hist'></td>
                    </tr>   
                        <td><label>Tgl Masuk</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='date_in' value='$date_in'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td><label>Tgl Keluar</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='date_out' value='$date_out'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td><label>Kerusakan</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='kerusakan' value='$kerusakan'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td><label>Biaya</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='biaya' value='$biaya'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td><label>Status</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='Status' value='$status'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td><label>Vendor</label></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='vendor' value='$vendor'></td>
                    </tr>                               
                </table>                                                    
            </form>     

        </td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' class='cekdelete' name='cekdelete' id=' cekdelete'     value='$id_hist'></td>                


                <td>$date_in</td>
                <td>$date_out</td>
                <td>$kerusakan</td>
                <td>$biaya</td>             
                <td>$status</td>                
                <td>$vendor</td>
                </tr>
        </table>


 $('.edithistory')
.button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-document" }})
 .click(function() {      
       record = $(this).parents('.record');
      $( ".formedithistory" ).dialog( "open" )
  });


 $( ".formedithistory" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
      OK: function() {                         
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },        
      Cancel: function() {           
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it seems you're creating a form with class `formedithistory` for every record of the table, you don't want that, instead of creating the DOM for every record put its code only once, outside of the table of records and open it sending the params of what record you will open

Comment: thank's G.Mendes it's work..